# k-space vector for N-body simulation box DFTs

Tags: python, fft, simulation, dft

I'm trying to write a particle mesh N-body simulation. In such a simulation the potential field is found by solving Poisson's equation using Fourier transforms. I have been following a presentation by Andrey Kravtsov (http://astro.uchicago.edu/~andrey/talks/PM/pm.pdf), but slide 15 has me confused. So far, I have assigned densities to a 3d grid from particle positions, and Fourier transformed the density grid. The next step is to calculate Green's function in Fourier space and multiply it with the Fourier transformed density grid, and afterwards applying an inverse Fourier transform to real space to obtain the potential grid. Through trial and error I traced the part that wasn't working correctly to the potential calculation, and specifically the k-space vector.

So, to calculate Green's function in Fourier space I need the Fourier axes usually called k-space vectors k_x, k_y, k_z. Using the slide it should be 2*pi*(k,l,m)/N_g for components k,l,m, where N_g is the number of grid cells. So far I've tried with these components running from 0,+1,+2,...,N_g. And -N_particle/2, ..., +N_particle/2 and several other iterations. The only thing that has produced reasonable results (can see a cluster in density slice projected on the same potential field slice) has been with using numpy.fft.freq in Python for specific values of the resolution/sample spacing. However, any resolution I chose (such as L/N_g, N_p/N_g, 2pi/N_g, etc.) did not scale properly with box size L, number of grid cells or number of particles and no longer worked for e.g. larger number of grid cells.

**My question is:**

How do I define my k-space vectors (i.e. the Fourier axes in reciprocal space) for a simulation with, along one direction, box size L, number of grid cells N_g and number of particles N_p?

I should add that the particle positions and velocities are all in code units as defined in the first few slides.

Minimum working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

M = 30 #Number of particles in 1 direction
Mn = 90 #Number of grid cells in 1 direction
Lx = 10 #grid physical size

u = np.random.random(M*M*M)
v = np.random.random(M*M*M)
w = np.random.random(M*M*M)

#Have purposefully taken smaller cube, to show potential works
planex = M*u
planey = M*v
planez = M*w

#Create a new grid
grid = np.zeros([Mn,Mn,Mn], dtype='cfloat')

#cell center coordinates
x_c = np.floor(planex).astype(int)%Mn
y_c = np.floor(planey).astype(int)%Mn
z_c = np.floor(planez).astype(int)%Mn

#in terms of the average density of the universe, doesnt matter for the 
#example
mass = 1.

#Update the grid 
grid[z_c,y_c,x_c] += mass

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.imshow(grid[:,:,2].real)
plt.show()

#FFT the grid    
grid = np.fft.fftn(grid)

#The resolution and the k-space vectors are the parts I am unsure about
resolution = np.pi*2/(M/Mn)
resolution = Lx/Mn

#Define the k-space vectors
k_x = np.fft.fftfreq(Mn, resolution)
k_y = np.fft.fftfreq(Mn, resolution)
k_z = np.fft.fftfreq(Mn, resolution)

kz, ky, kx = np.meshgrid(k_z, k_y, k_x)

Omega_0 = 0.27
a = 0.3
#Calculate Greens function    
k_squared = np.sin(kz/2)**2 + np.sin(ky/2)**2 + np.sin(kx/2)**2    
Greens = -3*Omega_0/8/a*np.divide(1, k_squared, where=k_squared!=0)

#Multiply the grids in Fourier space
grid = Greens*grid


#IFFT to real space

potentials = np.fft.ifftn(grid)

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
plt.imshow(potentials[:,:,0].real)
plt.show()
```

Large value for the resolution makes velocities explosive, small value and very small velocities. So what makes the right resolution?

This is my first time asking on Stack overflow, please let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

Best, R.

Comment: A minimum, working example demonstrating your issue would be helpful in debugging it.

Comment: Dear namesake, I added a working example

Comment: Thank you. You might find better help at [scipcom](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) as the folks there are more apt to understand the mathematics of what you're trying to do. If you think there's a code/programming issue, you'll want to clarify that and try to reduce the physics jargon in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will try there if this sees no answer :)